# Accurate translation of “bildungsfern”

Tags: translation, connotation, neologism

I have the feeling that all dictionary entries are not really cutting to the core of *bildungsfern,* because it is a more neutral, descriptive term to show that someone did have the privilege to receive good education, which is not his fault.

I also need the most accurate term, because I would like to add a new term to the scientific discourse, that is *nachhaltigkeitsfern* to show that these terms can be clearly delineated, though correlating. Any suggestions for either of the two?

Comment: Can you state what dicitonary entries you were dissatisfied with? Also, what do you want to introduce *nachhaltigkeitsfern* or its English equivalent? Finally, in my understanding *bildungsfern* is not strictly tied (though strongly correlated) to the education you received – otherwise there would have been no need to create this word and one could have used *gebildet* or something similar instead.

Comment: I agree. _Bildungsfern_ has the connotation of simply having no interest in education as such. In our society basic education is free, by and large, but while you can lead a horse to the water, as it were, it has to drink of its own accord.

Comment: If I understand you correctly then you are looking for an English word that describes a concept of which you have a clear conception and which you think is represented by the German word *bildungsfern*. That would make this a question about the English language, not the German language.

Comment: Isn't *bildungsfern* a term of political correctness that tries to avoid that people get upset when you call them what they are: *ungebildet*

Comment: @Ingo: this should be an **answer** not a comment.

Comment: @Takkat doesn't solve the translation accuracy problem, though...

Comment: @Ingo, nein. Als „bildungsfern“ bezeichnet man meist nicht Menschen, sondern deren Umstände oder Umgebungen, zum Beispiel ihre Elternhäuser. Und es bezeichnet nicht nur einen Mangel an Bildung, sondern auch ein geringes Interesse daran.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the English language.

Comment: It is borderline on topic as dictionaries fail, and to know what it means we need quite some knowledge in German. Please also note that this question is on top of search results when googling for "bildungsfern", "translate bildungsfern", or "German bildungsfern". It's these questions that may cause traffic to the site!

Comment: @Takkat: Then we should maybe ask a question about the meaning of *bildungsfern* without attempting to find a pinpoint translation into English, as this already seems to cause enough debate.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: we should also not be too picky on how to formulate a question. IMO some few German to English requests are fine as long as the German part needs our expertise. At least the title was great for Google... but admittedly the *nachhaltigkeitsfern* part is somewhat misleading - it should probably be asked in a more general question on the usage of the suffix *-fern.* *<-- **Wink mit dem Zaunpfahl***

Comment: Sorry for appearing so late and thanks for all the helpful comments. So I should split up this question, dear moderators? ;)

@Carsten: Thanks for the clarification. Exactly your -sadly German- definition is what I am looking for. 
This is where translations like "educationally challenged/disadvantated" or "aloof from education" fail, because I specifically want to point out that it is an imposed distance to education, because not every "horse is provided with the figurative water". And therefore it is also not just the descriptive "uneducated".

Answer (score 7):

Not quite getting the euphemism of using *bildungsfern* for *uneducated* but a nevertheless similar English term used in sociology or legal contexts (in the US) is:

> educationally disadvantaged

<sub>References: [USlegal Definitions](http://definitions.uslegal.com/e/educationally-disadvantaged-education/).  [Globe examples of usage](http://glosbe.com/en/en/educationally%20disadvantaged),  [Mondo facto](http://www.mondofacto.com/facts/dictionary?educationally%20disadvantaged%20youth)</sub>

Comment: If you want a very clichéd type of euphemism, you can also upgrade this to *educationally challenged.*

Answer (score 3):

The problem when translating this is that *fern* captures a lot of different aspects due to its highly figurative use. I think a good approach for capturing this is trying to do a similar figurative use in English by translating the term rather literal.

I therefore suggest to use one of the following adjective for *fern:*

- distant
- remote
- estranged
- aloof
- alien
- far

The final term would then be something like *aloof from education.*

My intuitive favorite is *[aloof](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aloof),* however I am not very familiar with that word and it seems mostly to be used in a positive sense – which can make for nice dissonance however.

Comment: 'aloof from education' doesn't sound at all right.